# Annotate labels in pandas scatter plot

Tags: pandas, plot, annotate

I saw this method from an older post but can't get the plot I want.

To start

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10),'y':np.random.rand(10)}, 
                  index=list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10]))
```

scatter plot

```
ax = df.plot('x','y', kind='scatter', s=50)
```

Then define a function to iterate the rows to annotate

```
def annotate_df(row):  
    ax.annotate(row.name, row.values,
                xytext=(10,-5), 
                textcoords='offset points',
                size=18, 
                color='darkslategrey')
```

Last apply to get annotation

```
ab= df.apply(annotate_df, axis=1)
```

Somehow I just get a series ab instead of the scatter plot I want. Where is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works, you just need plt.show() at the end.

Your full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10),'y':np.random.rand(10)}, 
                  index=list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10]))

ax = df.plot('x','y', kind='scatter', s=50)

def annotate_df(row):  
    ax.annotate(row.name, row.values,
                xytext=(10,-5), 
                textcoords='offset points',
                size=18, 
                color='darkslategrey')

ab= df.apply(annotate_df, axis=1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: By the way, Is there a way to solve the overlapping issue of too many annotations?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850142/matplotlib-overlapping-annotations

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that this doesn't work any more, however the solution is easy: convert row.values from numpy.ndarray to list:
 `list(row.values)`