# Automatically abbreviate the length string in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to automatically reduce the length of string in matplotlib if it conflicts with neighboring texts such as in:
[image]

What I'm looking for is if matplotlib detects a conflict with another text, it automatically reduce the texts in order for all the texts to be readable.

Note that one could of course [rotate the labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998621/rotate-axis-text-in-python-matplotlib) or [make the fontsize smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390393/matplotlib-make-tick-labels-font-size-smaller) to prevent overlap. But here I'm asking how to cut the text in case of overlap.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't detect such conflict; you will need to do it yourself. As a start one can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10739207/854988). Or check https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/__init__.py