# Is there a good generic method to get the bounding box of an arbitrary matplotlib Artist in data coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, transformation

I'd find it very useful if there was a generic way to obtain the bounding boxes in data coordinates for any arbitrary matplotlib artist.

For example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Ellipse
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

r = Rectangle((0, 1), 3, 2, color='r')
e = Ellipse((1, 0), 4, 2, 30, color='g')
l = plt.plot(np.r_[1, 2, 0, 3, 2], c='b', lw=2)[0]

ax.add_patch(r)
ax.add_patch(e)

ax.set_xlim(-2, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 4)
```

Getting the bounding box of the rectangle is very simple - I can just use its `get_bbox()` method:

```
print(r.get_bbox())
# [ 0.  1.  3.  3.]
```

However, neither the line nor the ellipse has a `get_bbox()` method. For the line it seems that I can do:

```
print(l.get_path().get_extents().extents)
# [ 0.  0.  4.  3.]
```

but the corresponding method gives me an incorrect result for the ellipse:

```
print(e.get_path().get_extents().extents)
# [-1. -1.  1.  1.]
```

The best 'generic' method I've found so far is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581470/1461210), and uses `get_window_extent()` to get the bounding box in display space, then the inverse axis data transformation to transform back into data coordinates:

```
def get_bbox_generic(a):
    fig, ax = a.figure, a.axes
    disp = a.get_window_extent(renderer=fig.canvas.renderer)
    return disp.transformed(ax.transData.inverted())
```

However this approach has at least a couple of drawbacks: it will fail unless figure has previously been rendered, and the transformed coordinates are a bit imprecise.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Support on this is a bit patchy, somethings really do not know how big they are until they are rendered (ex text).   Given that this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1635 is how is is done internally, I am not sure if there is a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

As of `matplotlib >= 3.6`, there are the [`Ellipse.get_corners()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.get_corners) and the [`Line2D.get_bbox()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_bbox) methods.

### Ellipse

The [`Ellipse.get_corners()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.get_corners) method returns the 4 corner points of the ellipse bounding box in data coordinates:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
e = Ellipse((1, 0), 4, 2, color='g')
print(e.get_corners())
# [[-1., -1.],
#  [ 3., -1.],
#  [ 3.,  1.],
#  [-1.,  1.]]
```

### Line

The [`Line2D.get_bbox()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_bbox) method returns the two points of the bounding box of the line:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
l = plt.plot(np.r_[1, 2, 0, 3, 2], c='b', lw=2)[0]
print(l.get_bbox())
# Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=4.0, y1=3.0)
```