# How to calculate the dimensions of a text object in python's matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to calculate the dimensions of a text object, given the characters in the array, point size and font. This is to place the text string in such a way that it's centered within a plot when using the matplotlib package in python, and will have to use the same units as the data being plotted.

Comment: There are options to align the text in different ways in `matplotlib`, see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/alignment_test.html)

Comment: This is a tricky problem, see the discussion [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#automatically-make-room-for-tick-labels)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, matplotlib allows for centering text (and other alignments). See documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/alignment_test.html).

If you really need the dimensions of a text object, here is a quick solution that relies on drawing the text once, getting its dimensions, converting them to data dimensions, deleting the original text, then re-plotting the text centered in data coordinates. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581194/matplotlib-text-bounding-box-dimensions) provides a useful explanation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

textToPlot = 'Example'

t = ax.text(.5*(xlim[0] + xlim[1]), .5*(ylim[0] + ylim[1]), textToPlot)

transf = ax.transData.inverted()
bb = t.get_window_extent(renderer = fig.canvas.renderer)
bb_datacoords = bb.transformed(transf)

newX = .5*(xlim[1] - xlim[0] - (bb_datacoords.x1 - bb_datacoords.x0))
newY = .5*(ylim[1] - ylim[0] - (bb_datacoords.y1 - bb_datacoords.y0))

t.remove()
ax.text(newX, newY, textToPlot)

ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
```

The result of this script looks like this:
[image]