# How can I label the clusters in sns clustermap

Tags: python, cluster-computing, seaborn

I am creating a clustermap with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

all_net_names  = ['early_vis', 'face', 'motion', 'scene', 'scene', 'scene', 
                  'dmn', 'dmn', 'dmn', 'dmn', 'dmn', 'dmn', 'reward', 'reward',
                  'reward', 'reward', 'reward', 'ofc', 'ofc', 'ofc', 'ofc']

roi_names = ['E', 'F', 'M', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5',
             'D6', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5','O1', 'O2', 'O3', 'O4']

n_roi = len(roi_names)
M = np.random.rand(n_roi, n_roi) # array to plot

net_ind = sorted(np.unique(all_net_names, return_index=True)[1])
net_names = [all_net_names[index] for index in sorted(net_ind)]
network_pal = sns.husl_palette(len(net_names), s=.45)
network_lut = dict(zip(map(str, np.unique(all_net_names)), network_pal))
network_colors = pd.Series(all_net_names).map(network_lut)
network_colors = np.asarray(network_colors)

g = sns.clustermap(M, center=0, cmap="vlag",
                   row_cluster=False, 
                   col_cluster=False,
                   row_colors=network_colors, 
                   col_colors=network_colors,
                   linewidths=0, figsize=(10, 10))

g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(roi_names, rotation=90)
g.ax_heatmap.set_yticklabels(roi_names, rotation=0)
```

It works and gives this output:

[image: clustermap1]

I could add labels corresponding to each cell but I also want to label each cluster with the unique network names as in here:
[image: modified cluster map]

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: It was a mistake in the code. It was the old name I used for 'all_net_names'. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe adding this at the end of the code?

```py
g.ax_row_colors.set_yticks(0.5 * (np.array(net_ind) + np.array(net_ind[1:] + [len(all_net_names)])))
g.ax_row_colors.set_yticklabels(net_names)
g.ax_row_colors.yaxis.set_tick_params(size=0) # make tick marks invisible
```

The start of each group is given by `net_ind`. To put the labels nicely centered, they should be placed just in the middle of their start position and the start position of the next label.  As the last group doesn't have a next label, we take the length of `all_net_names` as the end of the last group.

[image: example clustermap]

The same could be done for the columns:

```py
g.ax_col_colors.set_xticks(0.5 * (np.array(net_ind) + np.array(net_ind[1:] + [len(all_net_names)])))
g.ax_col_colors.set_xticklabels(net_names, rotation=90)
g.ax_col_colors.xaxis.set_tick_params(size=0) # make tick marks invisible
g.ax_col_colors.xaxis.tick_top()
```