# seaborn heatmap colorbar categories "squished" in row and column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

### question

Following the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988846/how-to-express-classes-on-the-axis-of-a-heatmap-in-seaborn) for making clustermaps / heatmaps with categorical row and column labels with my own data, I noticed the colorbars for each category do not stack neatly on each other.  Instead, they all jam into the same area.  I'll show you what I mean:

Here it is with one category per column and row:
[image]

And here it is with 3 categories per column and 2 per row:
[image]

Note how they all occupy the same area, and thus get squished.  Is this an issue of the aspect ratio being fixed?  Is there a way to manually resize each category via matplotlib?  What is the most efficient way to get them stacked on top of each other where each is sized and scaled uniformly?

### fix (sort of)

After upgrading seaborn to version 0.10.0 from 0.9.0 (and changing the color palette), I was able to control the size of the color bars with the new argument `colors_ratio=.06`.  However, now there is an enormous space between my y axis bar and the heatmap.  I guess it's time to post another followup question...

[image]

Comment: OK, that link should link now.

Comment: Did you try to change `colors_ratio=`? Default is 0.03, so 3% of the width. See [the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html). You might need to upgrade to the latest version of seaborn (0.10).

Comment: Did changing the `colors_ratio` work for you?

Comment: Yes, although I traded an old issue for a new issue, apparently.

Comment: You might want to experiment with `cbar_pos=(left, bottom, width, height)`. And maybe setting `color_ratios=` back to `none`

Comment: I experimented with the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792534/how-can-i-label-the-clusters-in-sns-clustermap), added an extra row and column of colors, and increased the colors_ratio. No gaps appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted back to 0.9.0, and the gap disappeared.  However, and I will just live with the weird color bars.