# How to get bounding box on matplotlib scientific notation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following matplotlib image, I want to get the coordinates for the bounding box of the axis scientific notation label - bottom right, enclosed in red.
[image]

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581194/matplotlib-text-bounding-box-dimensions), it explains how to get the pixel coordinates from any text instance.  The problem is, I can't find how to access this text instance from an Axes object.  I know that this text is related to the [ScalarFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) object that decides whether to use scientific notation, but looking at its source code, it doesn't keep track of the text instance.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is called "offset" (even though it may be a multiplier). You can get the text object via `ax.xaxis.get_offset_text()`. You don't tell in the question why you would need that though. Usually you would not need the coordinates of that text.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I need it because I want to be able to reverse engineer the chart: given the image, output the original data.  The offset is an important part of that, and to find it with machine learning, I need to know where the offset text is in my training data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Can I suggest that you provide the answer youself, given that you better know for which purpose this is used?