# How to align two matplotlib text-boxes side-by-side in the top-right corner?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I am trying to put two text-boxes side-by-side in the top-right corner of a matplotlib figure. I followed [this tutorial on text-alignment](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/text_alignment.html) and can place one text-box in the top-right corner. But I do not know how to add a second text-box such that the right-edge of the top-left box intersects the left-edge of the top-right box.

[image: MWE Figure]

The code to output run the minimal working example is below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)
shrink_factors = np.linspace(1, 0, x.size)
y1 = shrink_factors*np.sin(np.exp(-x))
y2 = shrink_factors*np.cos(np.exp(-x))

# get plot parameters
xlim = [np.min(x), np.max(x)]
ylim = [0, 1.125*np.max([np.max(y1), np.max(y2)])]
facecolors = ("red", "blue")
(color1, color2) = facecolors
label1 = "Label 1"
label2 = "Label 2"
text1 = "RED 1"
text2 = "BLUE 2"
text_background_color = "gainsboro"
text_size = 12
figsize = (12, 7)
# figsize = (7, 12)

# initialize plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=figsize)

# plot data
ax.plot(x, y1, color=color1, label=label1)
ax.plot(x, y2, color=color2, label=label2)
ax.grid(color="black", linestyle=":", alpha=0.3)
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
fig.legend(mode="expand", loc="lower center", ncol=2)

# add text-boxes side-by-side
text_box1 = ax.text(0.95, 0.95, text1, 
                    color=color1, 
                    fontsize=text_size,
                    horizontalalignment="right", 
                    verticalalignment="top", 
                    transform=ax.transAxes)
text_box1.set_bbox({"facecolor": text_background_color, "edgecolor": "black"})
text_box1_pos = text_box1.get_position()
text_box2 = ax.text(text_box1_pos[0], 0.95, text2, 
                    color=color2, 
                    fontsize=text_size, 
                    horizontalalignment="left", 
                    verticalalignment="top", 
                    transform=ax.transAxes)
text_box2.set_bbox({"facecolor": text_background_color, "edgecolor": "black"})

# finish plot
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had encountered a similar issue some time back. Here is what I did... This is based on some of the info provide in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581194/matplotlib-text-bounding-box-dimensions). Given below are the updates to your code...

1. Update the x position of the first text box to `0.9`, so that both the labels are within the plot
2. Once the first text box is plotted, add the below code.. this is similar what is explained in the post I mentioned. Note that I am using `transAxes` so that we have same coordinates everywhere. More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). Note the `bb_datacoords` will now have the x and y coordinates of the first textbox

```
#text_box1_pos = text_box1.get_position()  --> You code, not required anymore

r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
transf = ax.transAxes.inverted()
bb = text_box1.get_window_extent(renderer = r)
bb_datacoords = bb.transformed(transf)
```

3. Use the x1 position from bbox as the start point for the second text box, like below...

```
    bb_datacoords.x1+0.01, #text_box1_pos[0],
```

Note that, as mentioned in the above SO answer, the exact position is not known till the plot is done, so there is a small delta of 0.01 that you can add to make them non-overlapping. You can increase it (to say 0.02) if you want to see a small gap in between the two boxes.

The resulting plot looks like this... Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want to right-align the left box to the left x value of the right box. So you need to get the rectangles drawn around the text boxes. They are padded by a value of pad scaled with a mutation scale factor. To get these values you first need to draw the figure (you can do it without rendering to speed it up a bit).

Here is a minimal examples assuming both texts using the same (default) padding:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bbox_kwds = dict(fc="gainsboro", ec="black")
text_box1 = ax.text(0.95, 0.95, "RIGHT", ha="right", va="top", transform=ax.transAxes, bbox=bbox_kwds)

fig.draw_without_rendering()
pad = text_box1.get_bbox_patch().get_boxstyle().pad * text_box1.get_bbox_patch().get_mutation_scale()
x = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(text_box1.get_bbox_patch().get_window_extent().p0 - [pad, 0])[0]

text_box2 = ax.text(x, 0.95, "LEFT", ha="right", va="top", transform=ax.transAxes, bbox=bbox_kwds)
```

[image]