# How to modify ax.set_title to include differents colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text-coloring

I am plotting a specific figure using the following program:

```
alpha, beta = 0.5, 0.5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6,3))
ax.set_title(r"Predicted $x$ with Bayes Factor w.r.t. $\beta(1,1)$:" + "\n" 
             + "> 3 (green) or < 3 (blue)" + "\n" 
             + r"when prior = $\beta$" + f"({alpha}, {beta}) " 
             + f"[n = {n}] " + "-NO DATA-", 
             fontsize = '15')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to modify the instructions given to `ax.set_title` in order to have the text `>3 (green)` displayed in `green` color and the text `>3 (blue)` displayed in `blue` color, inside the whole title?

I tried to play with `r"\textcolor{green}{> 3 (green)}"` (as an example) but that turned out to be useless...

Should I need to split the `title` in several parts with different specifications in each part? But how to do that, if it is the case?

Or is there a nice pythonic way to do the job?

Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: No.  The title is all one color.  You can add your own text to the graph, however.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169052 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264305

Comment: Thanks for the links, but really not easy to implement. Following `Tim Roberts` suggestion, I rather vote to use `ax.annotate()` and specify `color = ***` inside the annotation...