# Matplotlib, how to disable text wrapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have rendered this latex expression using matplotlib, but it has wrapped the text and therefore given a multiline output.

[image]
I want the output to look like this instead:
[image]

I set wrap = False , but it still does this

```
t = plt.text(0.5, 0.5, expr, fontsize=320, fontweight='bold', wrap=False, color='white',  horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')
```

I am not sure why it is wrapping it to 3 lines still.

For reference, this is latex expression being rendered.

```
$\equiv\ \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{2}}{2} \operatorname{asin}{\left (x \right )} + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x}{4} \sqrt{- x^{2} + 1} + \begin{cases} 2 i \sqrt{x - 1} - 2 \log{\left (\sqrt{x} \right )} + \log{\left (x \right )} + 2 i \operatorname{asin}{\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right )} & \text{for}\: \left|{x}\right| > 1 \\2 \sqrt{- x + 1} + \log{\left (x \right )} - 2 \log{\left (\sqrt{- x + 1} + 1 \right )} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} - \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{asin}{\left (x \right )}$
```

How would i get the desired result?

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]. What is the backslash behind `equiv` for?

Comment: The extra backslash infront of equiv has been removed, but it is still unimportant, the latex expression itself is unimportant, the issue lies in matplotlib as it is textwrapping the expression, and i dont want that to happen, so i'm enquiring how this can be overcome @Im

Comment: See my answer down below on how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the backslash behind `equiv` in the latex formula.
Then, using the code from [this github](https://gist.github.com/ahwillia/c7e54f875913ebc3de3852e9f51ccc69), to which I linked already in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200414/matplotlib-dynamically-changing-width-of-plot) I get the desired output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'

def plot_equation(eq, fontsize=50, outfile=None, padding=0.1):
    """
    Function taken from
    https://gist.github.com/ahwillia/c7e54f875913ebc3de3852e9f51ccc69
    Plot an equation as a matplotlib figure.
    Parameters
    ----------
    eq : string
        The equation that you wish to plot. Should be plottable with
        latex. If `$` is included, they will be stripped.
    fontsize : number
        The fontsize passed to plt.text()
    outfile : string
        Name of the file to save the figure to.
    padding : float
        Amount of padding around the equation in inches.
    Returns
    -------
    ax : matplotlib axis
        The axis with your equation.
    """
    # clean equation string
    eq = eq.strip('$').replace(' ', '')

    # set up figure
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1])    
    r = f.canvas.get_renderer()

    # display equation
    t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '${}$'.format(eq), fontsize=fontsize,
        horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')

    # resize figure to fit equation
    bb = t.get_window_extent(renderer=r)
    w,h = bb.width/f.dpi,np.ceil(bb.height/f.dpi)
    f.set_size_inches((padding+w,padding+h))

    # set axis limits so equation is centered
    plt.xlim([0,1])
    plt.ylim([0,1])
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    if outfile is not None:
        plt.savefig(outfile)

    return ax

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_equation('x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}',outfile=__file__[:-3]+"1.png",padding=0.1)

    eq =r" \equiv \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{2}}{2} \operatorname{asin}{\left (x \right )} + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x}{4} \sqrt{- x^{2} + 1} + \begin{cases} 2 i \sqrt{x - 1} - 2 \log{\left (\sqrt{x} \right )} + \log{\left (x \right )} + 2 i \operatorname{asin}{\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right )} & \text{for}\: \left|{x}\right| > 1 \\2 \sqrt{- x + 1} + \log{\left (x \right )} - 2 \log{\left (\sqrt{- x + 1} + 1 \right )} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} - \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{asin}{\left (x \right )}"
    plot_equation( eq ,outfile=__file__[:-3]+"2.png",padding=0.1, fontsize=10)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the key is in the .format part. Thanks

Comment: The `.format()` is unimportant. I guess the key is more that you should reduce the fontsize to some reasonable number.