# Matplotlib - Change length in fancytextbox

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the following boxplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.text(0.7, 0.7, "test", size=50,
         ha="right", va="top",
         bbox=dict(boxstyle="square")
         )
plt.show()
```

[image: fancytextbox_example]]

How can you change the length of the box without changing the width?

**EDIT:**

What I want is:

```
plt.text(0.05, 0.7, "      test       ", size=50, va="top",
         bbox=dict(boxstyle="square"))
```

[image: fancytextbox_example_2]

But using spaces in the string seems like a pretty ugly solution. There's another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib text dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320205/matplotlib-text-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: create `FancyBboxPatch` with `matplotlib.patches` from where you can change the length and width, then add the text.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patches = []
fancybox = mpatches.FancyBboxPatch([0, 0.45], 1, 0.3,
    boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("square", pad=0))
patches.append(fancybox)
collection = PatchCollection(patches)
ax.add_collection(collection)
pth = plt.text(0.7, 0.7, "test", size=50,
         ha="right", va="top")
plt.show()
```

[image: _solution]